# Composition of Functions with Big-Oh

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm in the process of learning Big-Oh and came across an equality presented as a fact without justification:

$\sqrt{n + \mathcal O(n^2)} = \sqrt{n} + \mathcal O(n^\frac{3}{2})$

Is this so? What is the best way to approach a problem like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O and function composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761006/big-o-and-function-composition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in the limit $n \to 0^+$. One very useful tool for problems like this is Taylor series.

**Hint:** Write $n+O(n^2)$ as $n(1+O(n))$, bring a $\sqrt{n}$ outside of the square root, then try to use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Excellent! Very clear, and yet left me enough to think about for myself. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Actually, if I can dwell on this for a minute longer... as per your advice I was left with:

$\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1-O(n)}$ = $\sqrt{n}(1 + O(n) + O(O(n)^2))$.


Does $O(O(n)^2)$ collapse to $O(n^2)$ as expected?

Comment: Yes, it does. Informally you might imagine it unwinding like this: by the definition of Big-O, $$|O(O(n)^2)| \leq C_1 O(n)^2 \leq C_1 (C_2 n)^2 = C_1 C_2^2 n^2$$ for $n > 0$ small enough, so indeed $O(O(n)^2) = O(n^2)$ as $n \to 0^+$.